# Как сделать в android такое изображение

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутрь круга должен быть прозрачным

Comment: Обязательно в андроиде? В чём проблема в том же Photoshop или CorelDraw нарисовать её и сохранить в png или svg?

Comment: обычно такое делается через Канву, думаю в xml нельзя так сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто рисуете Shape "ring" с оооочень большой толщиной. Примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="50dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="500dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"
        />
    <size
        android:height="200dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        />
</shape>
```

И получается примерно так:

[image: Превью студии]